# Отличить эмулятор от физического устройства

Tags: c#, iphone, xamarin, тестирование, эмулятор

Тестирую мобильные приложения `Xamarin` под `Android` и `iOS`, тесты проходят как на реальных устройства так и на эмуляторах.

Однако недавно появилась необходимость, различать тест запущенный на эмуляторе и на физическом устройстве.

Вопрос: есть ли способ в процессе тестирования `.apk` или `.ipa` чтобы понять где работает приложение — на эмуляторе или реальном устройстве?

Есть ли какие нибудь системные параметры, которые на эмуляторе всегда отличаются от реального устройства?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На эмуляторе эти строки вернут истину:

```
Build.PRODUCT.equals( "google_sdk" );
Build.MODEL.equals( "google_sdk" );
Build.HARDWARE.equals( "goldfish" );
Build.MANUFACTURER.equals( "unknown" );
```

На C# это будут строки:

```
global::Android.OS.Build.Product
global::Android.OS.Build.Model
global::Android.OS.Build.HardWare
global::Android.OS.Build.Manufacturer
```

Но это бывает не всегда.

Можно попробовать так (Пример на Java):

```
if(Build.PRODUCT.matches(".*_?sdk_?.*")){
  //-- emulator --
}else{
  //-- other device --
}
```

Еще один способ (Java):

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String networkOperator = tm.getNetworkOperatorName();
if("Android".equals(networkOperator)) {
    // Emulator
}
else {
    // Device
}
```

То есть, если надо на 100% быть уверенным, что это эмулятор, придется комбинировать методы.
Например функция  [@AndroidCrop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32664737/9184466) (Java):

```
public static final boolean isEmulator() {

int rating = 0;

if ((Build.PRODUCT.equals("sdk")) || (Build.PRODUCT.equals("google_sdk"))
        || (Build.PRODUCT.equals("sdk_x86")) || (Build.PRODUCT.equals("vbox86p"))) {
    rating++;
}
if ((Build.MANUFACTURER.equals("unknown")) || (Build.MANUFACTURER.equals("Genymotion"))) {
    rating++;
}
if ((Build.BRAND.equals("generic")) || (Build.BRAND.equals("generic_x86"))) {
    rating++;
}
if ((Build.DEVICE.equals("generic")) || (Build.DEVICE.equals("generic_x86")) || (Build.DEVICE.equals("vbox86p"))) {
    rating++;
}
if ((Build.MODEL.equals("sdk")) || (Build.MODEL.equals("google_sdk"))
        || (Build.MODEL.equals("Android SDK built for x86"))) {
    rating++;
}
if ((Build.HARDWARE.equals("goldfish")) || (Build.HARDWARE.equals("vbox86"))) {
    rating++;
}
if ((Build.FINGERPRINT.contains("generic/sdk/generic"))
        || (Build.FINGERPRINT.contains("generic_x86/sdk_x86/generic_x86"))
        || (Build.FINGERPRINT.contains("generic/google_sdk/generic"))
        || (Build.FINGERPRINT.contains("generic/vbox86p/vbox86p"))) {
    rating++;
}

return rating > 4;

}
```